# Giving Arghya to Surya even when not visible?

Tags: practice, surya, vedic-rituals

I have watched several people giving *arghya* to *Surya*, even before sunrise (when sun is even not visible ).
Sometimes, people give *arghya* when sun in above the head. They'll just point to the east direction and give *arghya* just in a ceremonial or ritualistic gesture.

Sometimes, people live in flats and apartments, where the morning or evening or anytime, the sun might not be visible at all throughout the day.

Is this kind of *arghya* even valid ? Shouldn't the sun be rising in the east and properly visible, when *arghya* is given? Or even, mere symbolic gestures of the rituals are acceptable?

*(Obviously, I'm talking about general days when there's no emergencies (*aapaatkaalama-stithi*) like unchecked weather, etc)*.

And, also, how to resolve the problems of no sun visibility, due to infrastructural problems or other unexpected situations?

Answer (score 2):

```
காணாமல் , கோணாமல் , கண்டு

Kaanamal, Konaamal, Kandu
```

Above is a Tamil dictum for Tri-kala Sandhya-Vandana that explains when Arghya must be given.

Pratah - Kaanamal (morning - unseen i.e. before sunrise at 6)

Madhyan - Konaamal (afternoon - un-angled i.e. right above head at 12)

Sayam - Kandu (evening - seen i.e. before sunset at 6)

Symbolic gestures are also allowed e.g. cloudy sky is not an excuse to not do it.

Source - https://kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part19/chap10.htm